# I keep getting an error when running my program in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have recently started coding and I am using Pycharm and VS Code.
I encountered a problem and I cant seem to find any soloution to it, and I am to fresh to figure it out myself.

I run this simple program:

```py
count = 0
for number in range(1, 10):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
        print(number)
print(f"We have {count} even numbers")
```

In Pycharm it works, but in VS Code it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\HelloWorld\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from termios import CBAUDEX
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'"
```

Does anyone one a clue what I need to do specifically?

The tutorial I am following is also using VS Code, and he doesn't seem to encounter the same issue.

Comment: where in your code on line 2 is: `from termios ....`

Comment: I went in there and I had these three lines printed in the top of my file: 
from distutils.cmd import Command

from termios import CBAUDEX

from tkinter import FIRST. 

I removed them and now I dont get the error anymore : )

Comment: when you copy paste the file content in the question why are these 3 lines removed

Comment: I have programmed Python for many years and never used `from distutils.cmd`, where do you get these lines from, only one tkinter import line is very strange and `FIRST` on its own is useless it is a constant

Comment: what do you have in `d:\Coding\HelloWorld\app.py` ? As I rember `termios` is only for Linux or Unix

Comment: Hey, I don't want to be rude, but your file should have been checked for this earlier, as sometimes, when you are typing, VSCode may autocomplete something unexpected like an import, which will cause an error, this module is not found when imported, and causes an error

Comment: @furas I think this happpened due to the module not existing in his computer

Comment: @PythonProgrammer I think the same - as I remeber `termios` is for Linux/Unix and path `d:\Coding\HelloWorld\app.py` in error shows that OP uses Windows

Comment: This has happened to me before when typing and accidentally pressing enter. IntelliSense  autocompletes random imports at the top of the file. I don't know why this happens though.

Comment: @PythonProgrammer VSC does this only with Quick Fixes and the user has to select the Quick Fix, if it is done automatic he must use an extension

Comment: Oh I see, i really only started programming recently, so I don't know much about code editor configuration sorry, I  might have messed something up while setting up VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went in there and I had these three lines printed in the top of my file:
from distutils.cmd import Command
from termios import CBAUDEX
from tkinter import FIRST.

I removed them and now I dont get the error anymore!